# LastModifiedDate in workflow field update

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow field update which stamps the last modified date to a custom date field.

Right now I am in PST and I see lastModifiedDate as 12-28-2017 4.59PM and in backend 2017-12-29T00:59:37.000+0000.

And the workflow assignment also assigns the value as 12-29-2019.

So does workflow uses the GMT value and not the time that the current user is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the DateTime value to Date field, without providing any conversion it might use incorrect date.

Use `DATEVALUE` function in your formula for getting correct date:

```
DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)
```

Comment: Does it mean it is using GMT date right now? And will DATEVALUE() will provide date based on the current user timezone.

Comment: That's correct. It is not an issue with workflow but DateTime to Date conversion, also happens in apex by default.